# Мгновенная отмена анимации по клику на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Могу ли я отменить анимацию блока `<span>` при клике на кнопку `<div>`?

```js
setInterval(function() {
 $("span").animate({
     height: "90%"
    }, 1000).animate({
     height: "30px"
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<span></span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А зачем Вам setInterval?

Comment: @Чад, чтобы повторять анимацию

Comment: Мне почему-то кажется что для этих целей лучше использовать калбек на завершение анимации, иначе через некоторое время будут "артефакты" из-за наложения анимаций

Comment: Да, ещё почитайте про управление анимацией http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/custom-effects/, лучше использовать стандартные механизмы, чем через таймер творить велосипеды

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Нужно сделать задержку между повторениями интервала: на данный момент вы добавляете "дикое" количество анимаций в очередь на выполнение каждую секунду). Логичнее всего в данной ситуации использовать 2000 миллисекунд.
2. Нужно сохранить `id` устанавливаемого интервала.
3. При клике на блок нужно остановить интервал, вызвав `clearInterval(id);`.

```js
var id = setInterval(function() {
 $("span").animate({
     height: "90%"
    }, 1000).animate({
     height: "30px"
    }, 1000);
}, 2000);
$('div').on("click", function() {
    clearInterval(id);
});
```

```css
span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<span></span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

А ещё можно обойтись без использования `setInterval`, который в данном случае выглядит сомнительным решением, и запускать следующую итерации анимацию по завершению предыдущей:

```js
var $element = $('span');
function animation() {
    $element.animate({
     height: "90%"
    }, 1000).animate({
     height: "30px"
    }, 1000, animation);
}
animation();
$('div').on("click", function() {
    $element.stop(true);
});
```

```css
span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<span></span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: это не совсем _мгновенная_ отмена анимации. он же все равно пройдет если попасть на начало интервала

Comment: @Grundy тут, скажем прямо, я несколько домыслил за автора, решив, что останавливать текущую итерации анимации на полпути - плохое дело.

Comment: кстати, после редактирования, потерялся смысл и совсем не кажется что нужно все обрывать :-)

Comment: @Grundy когда я вопрос редактировал - я не пытался исказить его смысл, да и слово "мгновенное" как было в заголовке, так там и осталось. Как бы то ни было, я добавил в ответ вариант с мгновенной остановкой и без костыля в виде `setInterval`-a.

Comment: Похоже это у меня первое впечатление от прочтения было :-) А посмотрел что поменялось и правда - то же самое

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых использовать `clearInterval()` для удаления повторения. Во-вторых указать время для интервала, суммарно равным всей анимации. И в третьих у `jQuery` есть функция [stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) или [finish()](https://api.jquery.com/finish/) для остановки анимации.

```js
var animate = function() {
 $("span").animate({
     height: "90%"
    }, 1000).animate({
     height: "30px"
    }, 1000);
};
animate();
window.intervalId = setInterval(animate, 2000);

$('div').on('click', function(){
    $("span").stop(true, false);
    clearInterval(window.intervalId);
});
```

```css
span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<span></span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```